# How to set min to 2 and max to 10 characters if the character exceeded the textbox change to red color bg?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, textbox

I have the code below. I want my max character input to be 10 and min to be 2. But I tried and my textbox still changed to red when my minimum character entered was 2 or even less than 10 characters. I can't HTML maxlength or minlength here.

This condition `if (fname.value.match(/\S/))` checks if the textbox is not empty when it should check for whitespaces. I tried to use `!= ""`, but when I enter something it gets skipped when I debug this.

```js
function validation() {

  var fname = "";
  var add = "";
  var message = "";
  // retrieving ids
  fname = document.getElementById('fname');
  add = document.getElementById('add');
  // white to red
  if (fname.value.match(/\S/)) {
    fname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  if ((fname != '') || (fname.value >= 10 || fname.value <= 2)) {
    fname.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  // white to red
  if (add.value.match(/\S/)) {
    add.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  if ((add != '') || (add.value >= 10 || add.value <= 2)) {
    add.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (fname.value == "") {
    alert("Firstname is empty! Enter your firstname to resume");
    return false;
  }

  if (add.value == "") {
    alert("Address is empty! Enter your address to resume");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validation()">

  Firstname:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <br> Address:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="add" id="add">
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" onClick="validation(); return false;" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is this `fname.value.match(/\S/)` supposed to check?

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir it is supposed to be checking if there is an input by the user when this actually checks if there is a whitespace in there. I tried to use the != "" when the textbox is not empty, but it skips it when I debug the code.

Comment: Why don't you just use `if(fname.value.length)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the value's length is between 2 and 10, not the value itself. Like this:

```js
function validation() {
  var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
  var add = document.getElementById('add');
  
  if (2 <= fname.value.length && fname.value.length <= 10) { // if there is input between 2 and 10 characters, then set the background to white
    fname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }else {                                                    // otherwise, ...
    fname.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    alert("name is not valid!");
    return false;
  }
  
  
  if (2 <= add.value.length && add.value.length <= 10) {     // if there is input between 2 and 10 characters, then set the background to white
    add.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  else {                                                     // otherwise, ...
    add.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    alert("addres is not valid!");
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validation()">

  Firstname:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <br> Address:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="add" id="add">
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" onClick="validation(); return false;" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thought I understood the condition right and thank you. I appreciate the help :). That's the only thing that didn't work on my program.

Comment: You're welcome! Just put in mind that the values of inputs are just strings (they already have the `length` property)!